# Login system with password_hash

Tags: php, sql, session, password-hash

I am trying to login users that are added by an admin, but when I press login, nothing happens, just a blank page with the header login.php.
Here is the code I use to add users:

```
    <?php 
    include "connection.php";
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add students</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boosttrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
            <form action="adduser.php" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        Username will be generated automatically
                    </h2>
<br/>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="s_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new passowrd">        
<br/>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="s_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
<br/>
                    <label>Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="s_surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter surname">
<br/>
                    <label>Date of birth</label>
                    <input type="date" name="s_dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date of birth">
<br/>
                    <label>Year group</label>
                    <select name ="s_yeargroup">
                        <option  selected = "true" disabled="disabled"> Select one from below...</option>
                            <option value=1 >7</option>
                            <option value=2> 8</option>
                            <option value=3> 9</option>
                            <option value=4> 10</option>
                            <option value=5> 11</option>
                    </select>
<br/>
                    <button type="sumbit" name="btnAddUser" class="float" value ="Login">Create New User</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="../logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>


<?php 

if(isset($_POST["btnAddUser"])){

        $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['s_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $name = $_POST["s_name"];
        $surname = $_POST["s_surname"];
        $dob = $_POST["s_dob"];
        $yeargroup = $_POST["s_yeargroup"];

$usernamenew = substr($name, 0, 1);
$usernamenew1 = substr($surname, 0, 4);
$usernamenew3= $usernamenew.$usernamenew1;
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbluser (Username, Password, Role) VALUES ('$usernamenew3', '$hashed_password', 'Student')"; 
if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
 {
    echo "Error with Username or password";
 }
 else 
 {
    echo "Username and password created successfully. The username is ".$usernamenew3.".";
 }
$sql4= "SELECT ID FROM tbluser WHERE Username = '$usernamenew3'";
$result1= mysqli_query($conn,$sql4);
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$userid=$row['ID'];

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO student (name, surname, dob, yeargroup_id, tbluser_ID) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$dob','$yeargroup','$userid')";
if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql1))
 {
    echo "Error with Student info";
 }
 else 
 {
    echo " \r\nStudent has been added successfully.";
}
}
?>
```

And here is my code that I use to login users

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "connection.php";
$message = "";
$role = "";
if(isset($_POST["btnLogin"]))
{
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM tbluser WHERE Username = ? ");
    $stmt-> bind_param("s",$_POST["username"]);
    $stmt->execute();


    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if(password_verify($password, $row["Password"]))
            {
                if($row["Role"] == "Admin")
                {
                    $_SESSION['AdminUser'] = $row["Username"]; 
                    $_SESSION['adminid']= $row["ID"];
                    $_SESSION['role'] = $row["Role"];
                    header('Location: admin/admin.php');
                }
                elseif($row["Role"] == "Teacher")
                {
                    $_SESSION['ProfUser'] = $row["Username"];
                    $_SESSION['teacherid']= $row["ID"];
                    $_SESSION['role'] = $row["Role"];
                    header('Location: teacher/prof.php');

                }
                elseif($row["Role"] == "Student")
                {
                    $_SESSION['StudentUser'] = $row["Username"];
                    $_SESSION['studentid']= $row["ID"];
                    $_SESSION['role'] = $row["Role"];
                    header('Location: student/student.php');    
                }
                else
                    echo "Role is not recognised";
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could find my mistake, I would appreciate it. Thank you
My database in case you need it.
[image]

Comment: You're setting the username in the database to `$usernamenew.$usernamenew1;` but you're not doing that when you check the login. Why are you mangling the username like this?

Comment: @Barmar It's a school portal for my a-level coursework, and the way my school gave out usernames is always first letter of your first name, and first 4 letters of your surname, so I tried to copy that. Anyways, I'm getting the username using $_POST['username'], so I don't understand why the way I added the username in the database would make a difference?

Comment: I see that you know how to use prepared statements, since you use it in the login page. You should use that in the registration script, too.

Comment: Your column length is 45 but it should be 255.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` is fine.

You're only selecting the `Username` and `Password` columns from the table. So `$row["Role"]` won't be set and none of the `if` conditions will succeed. You should be getting the error `Role is not recognized` as a result.

Change it to:

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Username, Password, Role, ID FROM tbluser WHERE Username = ? ");
```

Also, add `else` statements so you know which `if` condition is failing when the login fails.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btnLogin"]))
{
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM tbluser WHERE Username = ? ");
    $stmt-> bind_param("s",$_POST["username"]);
    $stmt->execute();


    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if(password_verify($password, $row["Password"]))
        {
            if($row["Role"] == "Admin")
            {
                $_SESSION['AdminUser'] = $row["Username"]; 
                $_SESSION['adminid']= $row["ID"];
                $_SESSION['role'] = $row["Role"];
                header('Location: admin/admin.php');
            }
            elseif($row["Role"] == "Teacher")
            {
                $_SESSION['ProfUser'] = $row["Username"];
                $_SESSION['teacherid']= $row["ID"];
                $_SESSION['role'] = $row["Role"];
                header('Location: teacher/prof.php');

            }
            elseif($row["Role"] == "Student")
            {
                $_SESSION['StudentUser'] = $row["Username"];
                $_SESSION['studentid']= $row["ID"];
                $_SESSION['role'] = $row["Role"];
                header('Location: student/student.php');    
            }
            else
                echo "Role is not recognised";
        } else {
            echo "Password incorrect";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Username not found";
    }
} else {
    echo "Form not submitted correctly";
}
```

You don't need a `while` loop when fetching the row, since usernames are unique; there's just one row.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but it's still a blank page.

Comment: You should add more `else` statements so that you know which `if` condition in `login.php` is failing.

Comment: The error is now just Password Incorrect, but Anyways thanks, that was very useful

Answer (score 1):

From the [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) documentation, `password_hash` with `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, produces a string 60 characters long and other algorithms might produce even longer. Your `Password` field in the database is only 45 characters.

As per recommendation from the documentation, you should increase the field size to 255.